# Scrapy - Get Text from all matching divs

Tags: scrapy

I need to get text from all divs which has class "feature has-feature"

```
<div class="features as-columns list">
    <div class="feature has-feature">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
        </svg>
        "What If" Scenarios
    </div>
    <div class="feature ">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
        </svg>
        Audit Trail
    </div>
    <div class="feature has-feature">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
        </svg>
        Balance Sheet
    </div>
    <div class="feature ">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path d="M504 256c0 136.967-111.033 248-248 248S8 392.967 8 256 119.033 8 256 8s248 111.033 248 248zM227.314 387.314l184-184c6.248-6.248 6.248-16.379 0-22.627l-22.627-22.627c-6.248-6.249-16.379-6.249-22.628 0L216 308.118l-70.059-70.059c-6.248-6.248-16.379-6.248-22.628 0l-22.627 22.627c-6.248 6.248-6.248 16.379 0 22.627l104 104c6.249 6.249 16.379 6.249 22.628.001z"></path>
        </svg>
        Multi-Department / Project
    </div>
</div>
```

> I am using below code but it returns me blank strings. May be because
>   of svg tag in between:

```
product_features = ""
divs = response.xpath("//div[@class='feature has-feature']")
for div in divs:
    product_features = product_features + div.xpath("./text()").extract_first().strip() + "|"
product_features = product_features.strip("|")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector for short. Check this, for example:

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in response.css("div.feature.has-feature ::text").extract() if i.strip()]
[u'"What If" Scenarios', u'Balance Sheet']
```

Comment: Thanks! I like xpath more so this one also worked fine, response.xpath("//div[@class='feature has-feature']/text()").extract()

Comment: I remember, when I had problems with scraped data because they added space after class name, like `<div class="feature has-feature ">zzz</div>`. So with css selectors you can avoid such cases like: they added extra space, extra class, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure you can help me here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104633/scrapy-grab-all-product-details

Answer (score 1):

```
for div in divs:
    product_features = product_features + div.xpath("./text()").extract_first().strip() + "|"
product_features = product_features.strip("|")
```

You are using extract_first() which return the first element while if you check your extract() there are three values as `[u'\n                ', u'\n                "What If" Scenarios\n            ']`

To get your value use,

```
txt = [val for val in div.xpath("./text()").extract() if val.strip()]
product_features = product_features + txt + '|'
product_features = product_features.strip('|')
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure you can help me here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104633/scrapy-grab-all-product-details

Comment: Or just use xpath for that: `div.xpath('./text()[normalize-space()]').extract_first().strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [1]: [text.strip() for text in response.xpath("//div[@class='feature has-feature']/text()[normalize-space()]").extract()]
Out[1]: ['"What If" Scenarios', 'Balance Sheet']
```

(A nice XPath cheat-sheet can be found here: https://devhints.io/xpath )